# asp.net mvc ModelState IsValid - handle the return on false efficiently

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

A few co-workers and I are developing CRUD application with .net mvc4. There is a lot of dynamic content being rendered via jQuery depending on the choices the customer makes. The problem with this solution is that we have to make numerous hidden inputs to pass the additional data, in case ModelState.IsValid turns to be false, and rerender the view with the model and some ViewBags

Q1: is it a bad practice to render dynamically things and rely on hidden inputs instead of taking advantage (or is it an advantage) of the Session?

Q2: shouldn't it be more efficient if we don't use a form-submit methodology but instead we use ajax request via jQuery and render errors through JSON responses (which I think would be a  well-defined object for the whole application)?

Q3: related to Q2 - wouldn't it be faster to transfer JSON (key-value == ModelProperty - ErrorText) than rerender the whole view and send it over "the wire"?

Comment: "render dynamically things" Post some code examples ! How is your view's dynamic content loaded / rendered, is it backed by models, etc...

Comment: it is better to use hidden inputs since they represent the state of their particular page..i dont understand when you say Session, but if u will use Session, there are a  lot of chances of screwing up...for example u put the Id in session for following page - '/home/index?id=1'... and if user opens '/home/index?id=2' in a new tab, then ur session will have value 2..i hope u understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're asking for an opinion more than an answer.

If it were me, I'd place myself in a corner for ever considering using the Session for something like this :). But more seriously, I would just use AJAX. Have javascript gather your values on submit, or have it bound to a javascript view model (e.g. via knockoutjs) and then submit the values as a well structured object to the server. This sounds like it would be more consistent from what it sounds like.

Personally, I don't use form posts for anything other than plain Jane forms; where simple key value pairs make sense. The very moment I start to feel complexity work its way into the form structure, or the minute I'm already having to throw javascript at it, I just go ahead and use ajax. Especially if the form has to update as the user is filling it out (e.g. go back the server to repopulate a cascading drop down menu) -- then I'll just use knockoutjs to bind the form to a model and when the user is ready to submit, my model generates a well structured request object the fires it off to the server which gets automatically deserialized into a .NET object and it's smooth sailing from there. In my experience, this does add more coding and technical complexity. But in the end, it solves more problems than it creates and usually ends up being a better user experience as well.

Answer (score 2):

About your questions 2 and 3 : forms and ajax aren't mutually exclusive: if you're concerned about rendering only a part of the page upon form submitting, you should use Partial views and

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(...
```

instead of

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm(...
```

That's the mvc way of doing it.